# What does slice operation actually return in python

Tags: python, slice

"All slice operations return a new list containing the requested elements"
This is from the python tutorials.

But if this is the case then why does this piece of code behave this way:

```
>>> a = [11, 3, 1999]
>>> a[:] = [9, 78]
>>> a
    [9, 78]
```

1) if slicing returned a new list then why does the binding that I have done to the new one affect the original one. What does this suggest?

But then I have also observed this:

```
>>> b = [4, 5, 6]
>>> b[:].append(5)
>>> b
[4, 5, 6]
>>> print(b)
[4, 5, 6]
```

2) This shows that indeed a new list is returned. What is really happening when      we slice a list?

Please point out my ignorance. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Assignment to a *target* is not the same thing as using slicing in an expression.

Comment: for `a[:] = [9, 78]`, you're effectively doing `a = [9, 78]`... for `b[:].append(5)`, your return value is being trashed

Comment: @taesu: no, you are not. You are replacing the *elements in `a`*. Your alternative *creates a new list*. The difference matters when you have more than one reference to that list object.

Comment: What I am asking is if slicing was returning a new list, then the assignment I did would not have affected the original list. Right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are confusing *expressions* with *assignment*. Getting values (reading) is handled differently from setting values (writing).

Assignment (setting) re-uses syntax to specify a target. In an assignment like `a[:] = ...`, `a[:]` is a target to which the assignment takes place. Using `a[:]` in an expression produces a new list.

In other words: you have two different language statements, that are deliberately using the same syntax. They are still distinct however.

See the [*Assignment statements* reference documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements):

> ```
> assignment_stmt ::=  (target_list "=")+ (starred_expression | yield_expression)
> target_list     ::=  target ("," target)* [","]
> target          ::=  identifier
>                      | "(" [target_list] ")"
>                      | "[" [target_list] "]"
>                      | attributeref
>                      | subscription
>                      | slicing
>                      | "*" target
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> - If the target is a slicing: The primary expression in the reference is evaluated. It should yield a mutable sequence object (such as a list). The assigned object should be a sequence object of the same type. Next, the lower and upper bound expressions are evaluated, insofar they are present; defaults are zero and the sequence’s length. The bounds should evaluate to integers. If either bound is negative, the sequence’s length is added to it. The resulting bounds are clipped to lie between zero and the sequence’s length, inclusive. **Finally, the sequence object is asked to replace the slice with the items of the assigned sequence. The length of the slice may be different from the length of the assigned sequence, thus changing the length of the target sequence, if the target sequence allows it.**

(Bold emphasis mine).

Compare this with the [*Slicings* section](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#slicings) in the expressions reference documentation; slicing in an expression produces a [`slice()` object](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#types), which the `list.__getitem__` method interprets as a request for a new list object with the matching indices copied over. Other object types can choose to interpret a slice object differently.

Note that there is a *third* operation, the [`del` statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-del-statement) to *delete* references, including slices. Deletion takes the same `target_list` syntax and asks to *remove* the indices indicated by a slice.

These three operations are, under the hood, implemented by the [`object.__getitem__()`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__) (reading), [`object.__setitem__()`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__setitem__) (writing) and [`object.__delitem__()`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__delitem__) (deleting) hook methods; the `key` argument to each of these operations is a `slice()` object, but only `__getitem__` is expected to return anything.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I seriously doubt if one can say Python is *clear and consistent*, especially under the answer of question like this one. This simple example appears at the almost first chapter of the official Python tutorial, and you have to refer to the language reference to really explain what's going on. I'd say even in C++ I don't have to confront with the standard this early in my learning.

Comment: @Masquue the C++ standard is a *very* different beast from the Python documentation. I stand by my statement, Python is, relatively speaking, clearer and more consistent.